# Eclipse BIRT Freezes and dies violently with no warning

Tags: eclipse, birt, eclipse-neon

hope someone can help me with this. I'm creating a BIRT Report using ECLIPSE NEON when it suddenly and randomly freezes losing all unsaved changes. When this happens Eclipse process just sits there, not taking any input. I've added a few things to my eclipse.ini that obscure answers to similar problems said that should resolve the issue, but I've had no luck with them. This also happens to a few of my coworkers and none of them have any idea of why. 
Here's eclipse.ini

```
   -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
    -product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.appendVmargs
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
    -XX:+UseG1GC
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
    -Xms1024m
    -Xmx4096m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Dorg.e
```

I've found an error log in eclipse which seems to be related to the problem.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_AR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Fri Mar 01 10:37:48 ART 2019
Unhandled event loop exception

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:1757)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(CLabel.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.computeSize(CLabel.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLine$StatusLineLayout.computeSize(StatusLine.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.computeSize(TrimBarLayout.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.access$0(TrimBarLayout.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout$TrimLine.addControl(TrimBarLayout.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarLayout.computeSize(TrimBarLayout.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimmedPartLayout.layout(TrimmedPartLayout.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setLayoutDeferred(Composite.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:4252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3809)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

And here's the session data.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_AR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
```